# Which Tense should we use while telling Story/Experience?

Tags: tense

In the Below link writer has written in his blog about his experience in one the famous fair in India. He has used Present Tense.

https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/blogs/toi-edit-page/magical-moments-at-the-kumbh-mela-everybody-does-their-own-thing-at-this-meeting-place-of-humanity/

Can we Use Present tense in telling experience / Story? or we can use Past tense also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it is not OK to use present tense when talking about the past.

HOWEVER, as a literary construct it is accepted. The reason for this is that the story-teller brings all the experiences to the present by recollection, and then explains what happens while re-living those experiences.

Answer (score 2):

For narrative, past tense is far more common, and is what you should use, at least until you understand the difference in nuance between the various time frames and points of view.

Using the (first person) present tense is a legitimate choice of writing style, and can be effective in contexts like this, where the narrator is describing events as if they are taking place as the reader watches.  Children's stories are also sometimes written in the present tense, possibly because this helps young readers immerse themselves in the unfolding narrative.

In addition, stories may be written in the second person present tense, for example:

> **You cross** the room and **open** the drapes covering the broad picture window, revealing a beautiful view of the distant mountains, still partly concealed by the morning fog.

This style is fairly common in things like [visualization/meditation recordings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGOInMepo0U), where the narrator guides the listener on some kind of inner journey, but it is generally not used in novels and other written narratives, as it is considered artificial and childish.